# Hibernate com nomes de tabela dinâmicos

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, persistência

Bom Dia/Tarde/Noite Pessoal! em um cenário aonde uma tabela do bd deve possuir um nome e datas concatenados como isso ficaria com hibernate tendo em vista que o nome da base é anotado no model.

Como é:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="nome_da_tabela")
```

Como eu estou imaginando:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="nome_da_tabela"+data)
```

Gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer isso ou mesmo algo parecido, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Esta data seria única ou corrente ?

Comment: Corrente cara, é uma tabela que teria essa data na nomenclatura para "versionar" a tabela, por se tratar de um sistema de natureza fiscal é necessário manter as informações de tributações que com o  tempo são alteradas a data seria justamente para especificar de quando é a tributação.Apesar que mais específicamente seriam usados apenas o mês e o ano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se voce estiver usando Hibernate você pode extender a classe ImprovedNamingStrategy (que herda da interface NamingStrategy e gera os metodos) e sobrescrever o metodo que gera a tabela no banco. Os metodos e assinaturas pode conferir no link:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html

Sobrescreva os metodos conforme uso:

```
@Override
public String columnName(String columnName)
{
    return columnName;
}

@Override
public String tableName(String tableName)
{
    return tableName;
}
```

Comment: Quem vai herdar esse métodos de ImprovedNamingStrategy é o model que eu quero com o nome modificado não é?